# How to interpolate/upsample timeseries in SQL or Python

Tags: python, sql, datetime, time-series, interpolation

I know there are similar questions out there, but none of the solutions, I try, will work on my data.. I have my data stored in an SQL database and usually do any datatreatment in python.

I want to interpolate timeseries data (in either python or directly in SQL).

I have different time series:

1. One whith datapoints for every 10 minutes except for the last part of the series where it is only once every hour. I want to upsample the last section to every ten minutes as well.
2. I have several series which was meant to be every 30 minutes, but some measurements were skipped (IoT data). These needs to be every 10 minutes as well.

**My data:**

Measurement every 10min and  then every hour

```html
      A_LOC_FK A_LOG_FK           M_WL_time M_WL_level_m
0          100      100 2021-11-09 00:20:00         0.18
1          100      100 2021-11-09 00:30:00         0.19
2          100      100 2021-11-09 00:40:00         0.19
3          100      100 2021-11-09 00:50:00          0.2
4          100      100 2021-11-09 01:00:00         0.21
       ...      ...                 ...          ...
27025      100      100 2022-09-13 04:00:00        -0.37
27026      100      100 2022-09-13 05:00:00        -0.41
27027      100      100 2022-09-13 06:00:00        -0.39
27028      100      100 2022-09-13 07:00:00        -0.27
27029      100      100 2022-09-13 08:00:00        -0.15
```

Measurements meant to be every 30 min

```html
      A_LOC_FK A_LOG_FK           M_WL_time M_WL_level_m
0           10       10 2021-11-09 00:19:54      -2.0624
1           10       10 2021-11-09 00:49:54      -2.0624
2           10       10 2021-11-09 01:19:55      -2.0616
3           10       10 2021-11-09 01:49:55      -2.0616
4           10       10 2021-11-09 02:19:55      -2.0616
       ...      ...                 ...          ...
14552       10       10 2022-09-09 05:00:10      -0.0045
14553       10       10 2022-09-09 05:30:09       -0.003
14554       10       10 2022-09-09 06:00:13      -0.0016
14555       10       10 2022-09-09 06:30:10      -0.0008
14556       10       10 2022-09-09 07:00:12       0.0006

[14557 rows x 4 columns]
```

**In python I tried:**

I have tried to resample, but get the error *"Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'"*

Then I tried different kinds of "to_pydata"/"to_datetime" etc. but either got errors or turned all my datetimes into NaT.

I also did different variations of:

```html
datas_copy.M_WL_time = datas_copy.M_WL_time.apply(lambda x: start_date + pd.Timedelta(minutes = 10))
```

but none has worked so far

I feel like I've tried a lot more, but I have lost the overview..

**In SQL I tried:**

The closest I came to a success is this:
[Attempt to upsample in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8jrW.png)

But I know, I am doing it wrong as i get the error "*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'*"

Can anyone please help me and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post data and code as formatted text not images.

Comment: Thx! Just tried - is this what you meant?